# Can not set columns of db table in Laravel Php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

I am new to laravel.
I have three tables in my DB

1. `dsp_account` with fields `id,name_display,short_name`.

[image]

2. `dsp` with fields `id,dsp_account_id`.

[image].

3. `rtbcfg_region_dsp` with fields `dsp_id,status`.

[image].

dsp table connected to dsp_account table via `dsp_account_id` field.

dsp table connected to rtbcfg_region_dsp via `dsp_id`.

I try to create this sql query:

```
select distinct dsp_account.id,dsp_account.name_display,dsp_account.short_name
from dsp_account
inner join dsp on dsp.dsp_account_id = dsp_account.id
AND dsp.id 
IN(SELECT dsp_id
FROM rtbcfg_region_dsp
group by dsp_id, status
having count(*)>0 and status = 1) order by dsp_account.name_display ASC;
```

this is my code:

```
$all_list6 = DspAccount::select('DspAccount.id', 'DspAccount.name_display','DspAccount.short_name')
            ->join('dsp', 'dsp.dsp_account_id', '=', 'dspAccount.id')
            ->whereIn('DSP.id',function($query)
            {
                $query->select('dsp_id')
                ->from('rtbcfg_region_dsp')
                ->groupBy('dsp_id','status')
                ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 0 AND status = 1');
        
            })
            ->get();
```

this is the error that I got:
what I am missing:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DspAccount.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `DspAccount`.`id`, `DspAccount`.`name_display`, `DspAccount`.`short_name` from `dsp_account` inner join `dsp` on `dsp`.`dsp_account_id` = `dspAccount`.`id` where `DSP`.`id` in (select `dsp_id` from `rtbcfg_region_dsp` group by `dsp_id`, `status` having COUNT(*) > 0 AND status = 1) and `dsp_account`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

[image]

Comment: I would alias dsp_account as something without an "_" and see if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$all_list6 = DspAccount::select('dsp_account.id', 'dsp_account.name_display','dsp_account.short_name')
        ->join('dsp', 'dsp.dsp_account_id', '=', 'dsp_account.id')
        ->whereIn('dsp.id',function($query)
        {
            $query->select('dsp_id')
            ->from('rtbcfg_region_dsp')
            ->groupBy('dsp_id','status')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 0 AND status = 1');
    
        })
        ->distinct()->get();
```

You should use original table name `dsp_account` instead of `DspAccount` as it is model class name. I haven't debug the query but i answered about only syntax error. Thanks:)

Comment: OK it worked TNX very much, if I want to add the distinct, if you see my sql it has distinct in the start of the query. where the distinct should be written?

Comment: I have updated an answer, please go through it.

Comment: TNX it solved it